# MySql Unable to update a particular column even though sql executed successfully

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I encounter a weird problem. I have a myisam table name mytbl with the following columns

```
id - primary key auto increment
name - varchar(80)
state - int(1) not null default 0
counter - int(11) not null default 0
```

I run the following sql in phpmyadmin

```
update `mytbl` set `state` = 1 where id = 1
```

It return 1 row affected. But when I do

```
select `state` from mytbl where id = 1
```

The value remains 0! I have run both sql for few times and the results are same. 
I can update column name and counter correctly but somehow column state cannot be updated! Changing state to int(11) also doesn't work. I add a new column state2 exactly like state and it can be updated.

It's very weird. Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: if one row affected then it will be defiantly show the record.i think you miss something

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a myisam table identical to yours but it works here.

- Are you sure you are getting 1 row affected?
- Are you sure you are not in a transaction? Try running `commit;`

Comment: Absolutely sure and it's already in commited mode as I am able to update other columns just not the state column.
I can make it work in my local copy of MySql too. The problem only occurs in the server.